# EDSDK 2.11 and XCode 4.5.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, edsdk

im looking for a short tutorial for starting with EDSDK and Objective-C. 
Im using OS X 10.8 and XCode 4.5.1.
It starts with complaining about missing header files `windows.h`. Cant even compile the sample project. And the EDSDK Referance is not that helpful
Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a problem with the EDSDK header files.

To fix this go to your /EDSDK2.11.3M/EDSDK/Header (or the location you put your EDSDK to) and open the EDSDK.h file and make changes at lines 30 and 762:

delete **MACOS**
(there are 2 underscores before and after, for some reason it does not show here)
and replace it by
**APPLE**
(again, 2 underscores before and after)

Save the changes and close the file.

Open the EDSDKTypes.h and do the same changes at lines 25, 37, 88, 1335.

Also, don`t forget that EDSDK is currently for 32-bit only, so in XCode you have to be in i386 mode.

Comment: No way. Thank u so much. I figuered the i386 out but that problem described here was breaking my ballz ;) Couldnt find any other answer like urs on th web. THANKS!